# JavaScript: Function get calling Object

Tags: javascript, function, promise, parent

I would like to read the worksheet name into getSummaryDataAsync function.
Is it possible to read the calling object?
worksheet.getName() has the last value of loop when the async call returns.
How to pass the right value?

worksheets{"a","b","c"}

```
for (var i = 0; i < worksheets.length; i++) {
  var worksheet = worksheets[i];
  worksheet.getSummaryDataAsync({ maxRows: 1 }).then(
    function(sumdata) {
      if (sumdata.getTotalRowCount() > 0) {
        console.log(worksheet.getName() ); //the loop is already at c.
      }
    });
}
```

https://tableau.github.io/extensions-api/docs/interfaces/worksheet.html

Comment: You probably want to list what framework you are using as a tag and not random useless ones.

Comment: Which one is undefined? `worksheet`, `worksheet::getName` or the result of `worksheet.getName()`?